# access directory of  a webpage

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am looking for a way to access a folder in a site that contains index.html or index.php .
 But when I remove the index file, when I try to access list of contents from the url, I get

```
404 page not found
```

error ;

Is this possible to see contents of a folder with features that I said , if yes why ?

Comment: it is simple, because there's no such page on the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable directory listing in your `.htaccess` file that you would put in the directory that you want to browse:

```
Options +Indexes
```

But the fact that you are getting 404 error might also mean that the directory doesn't exist at all on the server. So make sure it exists and has a `.htaccess` file inside it allowing directory browsing.